# phpseclib implemetation to connect to unix box

Tags: php, unix, ssh, phpseclib

```
<?php
    include('Net/SSH2.php');
    define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);

    $ssh = new Net_SSH2('hostip');
    if (!$ssh->login('user', 'passwd')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }
    $cmd="bdf|awk '{print $NF}'";
    $ssh->exec($cmd,$output,$exit_code);
    echo $output;
    echo "Exit code: $exit_code";
    foreach($output as $row){
        list($mount,$usage) = preg_split('//', $row, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        echo "$mount $usage";
    }
?>
```

I'm trying to run the above code using the `ssh2` class of `phpseclib`.
This returns an error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wampserverdox\aargh.php on line 13

Where am I going wrong.
I want to format the output that is returned by the `exec()` function.

Comment: the `foreach` loop expects an array, apparently `$output` it's not one. do a `var_dump($output);` before the `foreach` loop to check what it is, and what's inside it.

Comment: what $output variable prints?

Comment: put exit after $output and see what you get.

Comment: Exit code: 1array(0) { } 
This is what it returns.

Comment: This worked properly when I ran it directly on the box, without the ssh2 class.

Comment: you need to escape $NF so as to send it to exec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Net_SSH2:

```
function exec($command, $block = true)
```

exec() doesn't seem to use the parameters you think it does...

Comment: Just to add to this.. the OP seems to be have been (incorrectly) assuming that $ssh->exec() takes the same parameters as PHP's exec function: http://php.net/function.exec